# Can I set my Column name by referencing a column from another table?

Tags: sqlite, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am using SQLITE3 on my raspberry pi, I have two tables (views), the schema for them both is below:

```
CREATE VIEW [PivotTemps1hr] AS
SELECT timeslot,strftime('%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S',timeslot,'localtime'),
AVG(CASE WHEN sensor_id = '28-000005e31c72' THEN value END) AS Server_Cab,
AVG(CASE WHEN sensor_id = '28-000005ea2eea' THEN value END) AS Study,
AVG(CASE WHEN sensor_id = '28-000005eb3986' THEN value END) AS Master_Bed,
FROM TempsSlot1hr JOIN sensors USING (sensor_id, sensor_id)
GROUP BY timeslot;

CREATE TABLE sensors (sensor_id text,sensor_name text);
```

See above how in my PivotTemps1hr table I have hard coded the field names, examples: *Server_Cab* and *Study*

I am wondering can I somehow make this dynamic by reading the field called *sensor_name* from the *sensors* table (the join already exists between the two tables)? That way if I move my sensor from one room to another I only have to update the sensors table and everything is automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded database, and designed to be used from within a 'real' programming language.
Therefore, it has no mechanism for creating dynamic SQL commands.

You have to recreate the view from outside SQLite.

Comment: could you recommend a 'lite' database software I can use on my Raspberry Pi device?

Comment: Would a DB such as MySQL be able to do what I desire in my initial question? I am thinking about re-creating my tables in MySQL.